# Set variable name and value through Function

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Hallo I am trying to create a function with two arguments. 
Argument ONE should set a variable name and Argument TWO sets the name of the custom field which is the value of the variable.

I need a function for this, because the variable should get its value from a custom field of different pages depending on 
- if { it's parent has the ID 77, get its own field }
- else { if it's parent doesn't have the ID 77, get its parent field }

This is what I tried, but does not work yet:

```
function variable_is_field($variable, $field) {
    global $post;
    if($post->post_parent == 77)        // if page parent ID=77
                $variable = get_field($field); 
    else 
                $variable = get_field($field, $post->post_parent;); 
}

variable_is_field("$my-variable1", "my-custom-field1");
echo $my-variable1;
```

Any idea what's wrong with the code?

Comment: First of all your $variable does nothing, it's being lost. Why do you need it as argument? I think you don't need it at all. Anyway, it's not working because you do not return anything within your function. You should do return $variable;

Comment: Indeed, I was thinking too complicated. I am now using only the "field" argument, which makes much more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i can propose 2 solutions

if you need it only on this scope and one time like comment suggested so the code will be:

```
function variable_is_field($field) {
    global $post;
    $variable = null;
    if($post && $post->post_parent == 77)        // if page parent ID=77
                $variable = get_field($field); 
    else 
                $variable = get_field($field, $post->post_parent;); 

    return $variable ;
}

$my-variable1 = variable_is_field("my-custom-field1");
echo $my-variable1;
```

else if you need it globally you can try somenthing like dis

```
global $my-variable1;
function variable_is_field($field) {
        global $post;
        global $my-variable1;
        if($post && $post->post_parent == 77)        // if page parent ID=77
                    $my-variable1= get_field($field); 
        else 
                    $my-variable1 = get_field($field, $post->post_parent;); 
    }

variable_is_field("my-custom-field1");
echo $my-variable1;
```

Hope that this can help.